# How to populate a specific matrix within a single loop

Tags: python, matrix

I have the following lists. A of 100 numbers and B, which stores N number of indices:

```
A = [10,20,30,40] # Just 4 elements to keep the list short
B = [1,3]
```

My goal is to write a logic, within a single loop, that creates C within the following specifications:

- Values of the first columns are values of A so given A right now, the matrix would have 4 rows.
- There will be N additional columns within this matrix where each column has 0 values in every index except the Nth index, where the values will be one.

So for the above problem, the matrix should look like this:

```
C = [[10,0,0]
     [20,1,0]
     [30,0,0]
     [40,0,1]]
```

This was my attempt:

```
A = [10, 20, 30, 40]
B = [2, 3]
C = []
nest = []

for i in range(0, len(A)):
  nest.insert(A[i], 0)

  if i in B:
    indx = B.index(i)
    nest.insert(1, indx)
  else:
    nest.insert(0, i)

  C.append(nest)
  nest.clear

print(C)
```

And this is the output:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I am trying to solve this in a single loop. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why is there `10, 20, ..` in `A` but `1000, 2000, ...` in `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're after this:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40] # Just 4 elements to keep the list short
b = [1, 3]

c = [[av] + [1 if ai == bv else 0 for bv in b] for ai, av in enumerate(a)]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[10, 0, 0], [20, 1, 0], [30, 0, 0], [40, 0, 1]]
```

I'll grant you that the list comprehension technically still has "2 loops", but since you're using `index()` for a lookup in your solution, that doesn't change the order of magnitude (big O) of the operation, so that seems immaterial.

Note that your logic inside the loop is also just wrong: you check if the current index in `A` is in `B` and then insert either the index of `i` in `B` in the first position, or insert 0 in the `i`th position. You then proceed to add `nest` to `C` but keep modifying `nest` in other iterations.

This has several problems: the inner list in your code is always the same list, it's just in there "N" times. And it will be constructed incorrectly, since you don't even call `.clear`, it's just stated there, so it does nothing. This explains why your inner lists have 2*"N" elements (I won't say 'each', because they are all the same list).

A fixed version of your code could look like this:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40]  # Just 4 elements to keep the list short
b = [1, 3]

c = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    nest = [a[i]] + len(b) * [0]

    if i in b:
        indx = b.index(i) + 1
        nest[indx] = 1

    c.append(nest)

print(c)
```

Performance-wise they are very close (a million iterations):

```
comprehension:  1.3870112000004156
loop and index: 1.2418508000009751
```

I'd pick the comprehension for readability, but if you need performance and somehow still want to do this in Python, your code with my fixes and optimisations (not relying on `.insert`, but straight up construction) does the trick.

User @accdias suggested using truthiness and the ternary expression for even shorter code using `int(ai == bv)`, but this is slower:

```
truthy ternary: 1.8386486999988847
```

Comment: The runtime is O(n^2), right? And why doesn't index make a difference?

Comment: You have `indx = B.index(i)` inside your loop, which is a lookup that will add a similar hit to the straightforward and efficient double loop I posted as part of a list comprehension (note that you even precede the call to `.index()` with `if i in B`, which adds another similarly heavy operation). If you're curious, run your code (once it works) against the code I provided here and see what the performance difference is.

Comment: It can be shortened to `c = [[av] + [int(ai == bv) for bv in b] for ai, av in enumerate(a)]`, but it will turn the code less obvious.

Comment: Agreed @accdias, although I'm not sure the truthy conversion is faster than the ternary operator, but that'd definitely be something to test for someone who really wanted this to fly. Shorter isn't always better though so I would pick readability (obviousness) over speed unless speed is needed.

Comment: Is there no way to do this in a single loop? @Grismar

Comment: @oo92 - there is, although you might get docked points for the `in` and `.index()` depending on the way the question is phrased. Technically, there's only one loop in the fixed version of your code I just added, but if the requirement is to do it within specific big O, you might still be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

How about no loops? Or is the loop a requirement? There are probably still some loops hidden in here, but highly optimized numpy-code in C, so it should be pretty performant.

```py
import numpy as np


A = [10, 20, 30, 40]
B = [1, 3]

C = np.zeros((len(A), len(B)+1))
C[:, 0] = A
C[B, np.arange(1, len(B)+1)] = 1
```

Gives the expected result:

```
[[10.  0.  0.]
 [20.  1.  0.]
 [30.  0.  0.]
 [40.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: How did you print this? When I print C, I get: `[[1.e+03 0.e+00 0.e+00]
 [2.e+03 0.e+00 0.e+00]
 [3.e+03 1.e+00 0.e+00]
 [4.e+03 0.e+00 1.e+00]]`

Comment: In my tests and oddly enough, `numpy` is two times *slower* than the loop equivalent. The loop version time is 1.8195667330292054, and the `numpy` version time is 3.6151542009902187, measured with `timeit(number=1_000_000)`.

Comment: @oo92, For me it looks like that for `print(C)`, I think this is maybe a setting for the output-format that differs (the values are the same after all). Maybe it has something to do with this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html. Did you try the code separate in a new file or in your existing setup, maybe there are some settings that are set that differ from the default, or you maybe have a different numpy-version that changed the print-format (mine is 1.23.1).

Comment: @accdias that is indeed odd. How big are the arrays that you tested, are those only 4x3? Could be that numpy has some additional setup-costs so you have less performance for small arrays, but in that case performance doesn't matter anyway. For bigger arrays I would think a pure numpy implementation would be miles ahead compared to looping in python.

Comment: @MangoNrFive, I used the exactly same lists you posted. Perhaps it can be improved if we change them to `np.array()` instead. I will try that.

Comment: @MangoNrFive What if A was `[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]`? Would you be able to adjust your code where the output looks like `[[1000, 0, 0], [2000, 0, 0], [3000, 1, 0], [4000, 0, 1]]`?

Comment: By using `np.array()` improve it a little, but it is still slower than the loop version. I got 3.001444529974833 with `timeit()`.

Comment: @accdias, ok I think the reason is the setup-cost in numpy that you have for a small array too. But numpy should scale a lot better for bigger arrays. Try with arrays of length 1000 or more.

Comment: @MangoNrFive, I guess you are right in respect of the size of the lists.

Comment: @oo92, just change the A-array to `[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]` then. I just used your example, but that should work for any 1D-array.

Comment: I did and the output was `[[1.e+03 0.e+00 0.e+00]  [2.e+03 0.e+00 0.e+00]  [3.e+03 1.e+00 0.e+00]  [4.e+03 0.e+00 1.e+00]]`

Comment: @oo92 It is the correct result it is just printed differently in your setup (1000. == 1.e+03), try `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` before the print.

Comment: @MangoNrFive, you are right. For a `100` elements list, the loop version took 34.137083726003766, while `numpy` with `array()` took only 2.909940407029353, making it almost 17 times *faster*. `numpy` with lists took 8.903874907991849, BTW.

Comment: As one last note, to get rid of the floats inside `C`, replace `C = np.zeros((len(A), len(B)+1))` with `C = np.zeros((len(A), len(B)+1), dtype=int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in plain python with a single for loop and without any libraries.

```
A = [10,20,30,40]
B = [1,3]

num_rows = len(A)
num_cols = 1+len(B)

C = []

for i in range(num_rows*num_cols):
    col = i%num_cols
    row = int(i/num_cols) # Find the row and column for i
    if len(C)<num_rows:
        C.append([]) # Dynamically create a new row
    if col==0:
        C[row].append(A[row]) # First element should be from A
    else:
        if B[col-1]==row: # Check if the row of i matches the index from B
            C[row].append(1)
        else:
            C[row].append(0)

print(C)
```

Output

```
[[10, 0, 0], [20, 1, 0], [30, 0, 0], [40, 0, 1]]
```